# Combining two colors to create a new color not saving properly

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to combine the color red and blue to create purple using Pillow, this is the code I have.

```
from PIL import Image

red = Image.open('red.jpg')
blue = Image.open('blue.jpg')

red.putalpha(120)
blue.putalpha(120)

blue.paste(im=red, box=(0,0), mask=red)

blue.show()

blue.save('res.png')
```

However, when I ask it to show me the picture, I see it for a brief second then it disappears. I tried saving it to a file but it also does appear to be there either though the file is taking up memory showing me that there is something in that file but it is just not visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to combine colours, you need to make:

- the bottom layer (layer 0) have 100% opacity,
- the second layer (layer 1) have 50% opacity,
- the third layer (layer 2) have 33.33% opacity

In general, layer N, needs opacity `1/(N+1)` opacity.

So, as you have 2 layers, your opacities should be 100% and 50%.

There's a nice tutorial [here at Cambridge in Colour](https://www.cambridgeincolour.com/tutorials/image-averaging-noise.htm).